# Which type of CSS is faster internal or external?

Tags: html, css

I am getting some seconds of delay in CSS to load.
I am using Internal CSS.

Answer (score 1):

External CSS requires a separate HTTP request so will load more slowly on initial load (although HTTP 2 is changing this) but for subsequent loads will be cached and load much faster. (That said, if the CSS is particularly long then being able to download it in parallel may offset the drawbacks of the extra request).

Inline CSS has the same number of bytes but doesn't have the overhead of the extra HTTP request… but has to be reloaded every time a document that includes it loads so will be significantly slower in the long run.

Answer (score -2):

External css is faster as the browser will cache the file and make it load faster.